# How to draw a line in OCaml?

Tags: graphics, ocaml

I try to draw something in OCaml (try.ocamlpro.com).
I'm not sure how to draw a line, for example x=y using the function "plot x y". Eventually I tried something like this which clearly doesn't work:

```
open Graphics;;
Graphics.open_graph " 200x200";;
       for i = 0 to x do
        plot i (f i)
       done
    let g x = 2*x
read_line ();;
```

Any help (or examples) ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see what is your problem. When I try your code, modified a little bit, I can draw a line as you want. First you need to initialize your window:

```
open Graphics;;
Graphics.open_graph " 200x200";;
```

Then you need to define your function `f`:

```
let f x = x + 1;;
```

And then just draw the line using the function `plot`

```
for i = 0 to 200 do
   plot i (f i)
done;;
```

Voilà !

Answer (score 3):

There is also `Graphics.lineto`, which is based on a turtle-type system:

```
Graphics.open_graph " 200x200";;
Graphics.lineto 100 100;;
```

Changes the current point (defaults to `0, 0`) to the supplied `x y` point and draws a line connecting the two.

You can set the current point with `moveto : int -> int -> unit`.

See the [docs](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Graphics.html) for more.